# Dvd-rom drive on my Thinkpad T41- is really really loud is there a way to fix this or should I get a new one?

Tags: dvd, thinkpad

After looking online I found that people have had the same problem and it can be fixed through going into the windows power management settings (though I couldn't really find what to do when I'm there.) Is there a way to fix this in Ubuntu? I bought the laptop used and everything else on it has been working great.